# SIGSEGV exception and app crush, trying to find the problematic variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, segmentation-fault

I'm getting an exception in my app(via Ubertesters SDK) when app goes into background and pop back to foreground:

```
Signal 11 was raised. 
Signal defenition:
Signal 11 - SIGSEGV -   segmentation violation  -   Use of a pointer that has not been initialized or points to an object that no longer exists (ie: forgot to retain); see also TerminateExplicitListWithNil 
CallStack:
(
    "1   MobileControl                       0x00000001000fa9f4 SignalUbertestersHandler + 200",
    "2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000018f4cbb0c _sigtramp + 56",
    "3   UIKit                               0x0000000185a90798  + 100",
    "4   UIKit                               0x0000000185a90798  + 100",
    "5   UIKit                               0x0000000185a906a0  + 208",
    "6   MobileControl                       0x000000010007ee44 -[LocationTracker getBatteryInfo] + 100",
    "7   MobileControl                       0x000000010007c974 -[LocationTracker getMyInfoUsingLocation:] + 684",
    "8   MobileControl                       0x000000010007df7c -[LocationTracker saveLocation] + 1012",
    "9   MobileControl                       0x000000010007b7d0 -[LocationTracker startServiceListener] + 1564",
    "10  MobileControl                       0x000000010007af8c -[LocationTracker timerTaskInterval] + 372",
    "11  MobileControl                       0x000000010007b124 __36-[LocationTracker timerTaskInterval]_block_invoke + 44",
    "12  MobileControl                       0x00000001000411b4 __62-[NSTimerTask scheduleTimerTaskInterval:timeValue:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 960",
    "13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018f338014  + 24",
    "14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018f337fd4  + 16",
    "15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018f33f2b8  + 556",
    "16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018f33f4fc  + 76",
    "17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018f4cd6bc _pthread_wqthread + 356"
)
(null)
```

I'm trying to recreate the exception and can't figure out how.

I understand that one of the following variables in those functions are no longer exists, but how can I find which one is it and handle it?